# Angular project in GIT. Can't develop locally

Tags: angular

There is an angular project in a GIT repo. From a vanilla system (Mac OS-X Mojave 10.14.6) I'd like to clone it, install whatever Angular components are required, and continue dev on the project but I can't seem to get a dev environment working.

npm version 6.10.2
node version 10.16.2

I clone the repo and using bash, navigate into the directory with package.json.

```
$npm install
$ng serve
```

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/ng: No such file or directory

From what I understand, *npm install* should install whatever I need.

This is the contents of my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "ng-dsl-edit",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "ace-diff": "^2.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "diff-match-patch-ts": "^0.2.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-diff": "^0.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: angular version?

Comment: @joyBlanks : I posted the contents of my package.json file. What I would like to do is pull down the project from GIT, and make a local angular install to whatever version the package.json wants.

Comment: Have you tried using `npm i` inside current directory

Comment: $npm install
Yes, I did. it creates a long list of peer dependencies that I need to install manually. I try to follow it down the rabbit hole only to find that I seem to have an every growing list of "dependencies".

There must be an easier way.

Comment: If you can provide git access it will easy

Comment: You need to install angular-cli globally first using this:   
`npm install -g @angular/cli`  Then you can run `ng serve`

Comment: @nadhir, I'm faced with a situation where I want different CLIs for different projects on my system. I realize you can use npx for this. But for testing, I did install a global version 7.0.7. There is no version mismatch warning, but ng serve still returns an error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could to use `npm start` instead of `ng serve`.

---

**Why that happen?**

Because on your environment there is no `ng` in global scope so you will get that error. You can also run `npm install -g @angular/cli` to make it available in global scope.

---

**Why `npm start` works?**

Inside `package.json`, you can see there are some commands inside `script` block. With that, nodejs will find the binary file in local scope (inside folder `node_modules/.bin`), you've ran `npm install` already so that `ng` will available in local scope.

Hope that helps!

Comment: npm start works. now I have some other errors, but at least I'm running in the specified version, and by only running npm install. Thanks. If I wish to bump the version to the latest/greatest, is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @paiego, You shouldn't just upgrade the version. For the upgrading stuff, you should take a look at the migrating documentation from Angular to upgrade from older version to newer version. Because if we just install latest version then a lot of current code is not compatible with latest version

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Angular cli globally.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

or

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@7.X
```

Seeing you have a 7 project